# can an analytic function be smooth but not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Can an analytic function, real or complex, be smooth but not continuous?

Here, smooth means infinitely differentiable.

Naively, a function could be of the form

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2  & \text{ for } x\leq 1 \\ x^2+1  & \text{ for } x>1 \end{cases}
$$

Which is infinitely differentiable, but not continuous at $x=1$.

I'm not an expert, but my intuition is that analytic means a function can be represented by a Taylor series at any point in its domain, which means the radius of convergence must be non-zero .. and this is not the case at the discontinuity. Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: What is defenition of the analytic function?

Comment: Your function is not differentiable at $x=1$, so it is not infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Differentiable implies continuous!

Comment: Why do you claim that $f$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Your function is not infinitely differentiable. related good exercise: show that
$$ g(x)= \begin{cases} e^{-1/x} & x>0 \\  0 & x\le 0 \end{cases}$$ defines a continuous, smooth function

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I claim it is infinitely differentiable because $f'(x)=2x$, $f''(x)=2$ for all $x$, and higher order derivates are all 0. Furthermore, the $f'(x)\rightarrow 2$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ from above and below. Thanks for your patience with my self-teaching...

Comment: You are wrong. You have $f'(x)=2x$ if $x\ne1$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $1$, since the limit $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ does not exist. More precisely, the limit $\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$ does not exist (in $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - thanks, this is helpful for me to develop a deeper intuition for what differentiable means, more than what I was taught at school. Also - if you want to copy this as an 'answer', I'll mark it as done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your function $f$ is not infinitely differentiable. In fact, it's not even differentiable, since it is not differentiable at $1$. Since $f(1)=1$, asserting that $f$ is differentiable at $1$ means that the limit$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-1}{x-1}$$exists and it is a real number. But this does not happen, since$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{f(x)-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{x^2}{x-1}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

The question as posed is a little confusing. A differentiable function is necessarily continuous. Your example is continuous on the domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$. On the same domain, the function you have defined is analytic, because it is analytic on the two connected components of the domain, $(-\infty, 1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. However, there is no extension of this function to all of $\mathbb{R}$ that is still analytic because, as you have observed, such an extension cannot even be continuous.